# Query from three models containing many-to-many relationship in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have three models. Service, Partner, Location. A partner provides a service in some locations. Relationships are Service belongsToMany Partner, Partner belongsToMany Location. Now i want to do something like this:

```
$service=Service::find(1);
```

Now find a partner for this service for a specific location. I can do it using join but how to do with eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing like this

```
$service->partners()->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($location)
{
   $query->where('id', $location);
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that are only two many-to-many relationships.

So, my approach for getting the Locations of a distinct Service would be:

```
Locations::whereHas('partners.services', function ($query) {
        $query->where("id", $serviceId);
    })->get();
```

The `whereHas` function filters only Locations that have partners which are linked to at least one service. Furthermore the closure is setting another criteria, the `$serviceId`.

To get a partner for a specific service on a specific location:

```
Partner::whereHas('services', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', $serviceId);
    })->whereHas('locations', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', $locationId);
    });
```

You can also query for other things like names, dates and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In service model (service.php)

```
public function partner() {
    return $this->hasMany('Partner')->with('location');
}
```

In partner model (partner.php)

```
public function partner() {
    return $this->hasMany('location');
}
```

in your controller:

```
$service=Service::with('partner')->find(1);
```